# How to compile a MacOS app that's trying to compile an iOS SPM package?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, branch.io

I have an app that I want to target iOS and MacOS, except I have an SPM package which is strictly iOS implementation of Branch (linking SDK).

When I target Mac device, it tries to compile that SDK and fails because it internally imports UIKit. [image]

How can I get around this, I'm at a loss atm. I've also tried importing their MacOS SDK package but it is at odds with the iOS version because they both have the same package name. Any thoughts?

Comment: You might have to create your own package where you only compile the correct version depending on the target

Comment: You can use moduleAliases to get around identical module names.